# How do I add an if and else statement to python?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python and I'm trying to add if/else statements.

For example, I have this script that changes the file names within a directory to something else:

```
import os

#changes directory
os.chdir('/home/Documents/agreements')

for f in os.listdir('/home/rachellegarcia/Documents/agreements'):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_patient, f_conf, f_agmt, f_email = f_name.split('_')
    f_agmt_type, f_agmt_staff = f_agmt.split('-')

    #sets the new name
    new_name = '{}-{}{}'.format(f_agmt_staff, f_email, f_ext)

    #renames the file
    os.rename(f, new_name.replace('-', '@'))
```

What I would like is if a new file gets added to the directory, then it'll change it too.

But I think because don't have an if/else statement I get an error:

```
File "/home/Documents/python/renamefiles.py", line 8, in <module>
  f_patient, f_conf, f_agmt, f_email = f_name.split('_')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

So, I wanted to know if I can add something like;

if the new_name is set, then skip and continue the loop.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Place the code in text format in your question instead of an image, that way others could try it and easily find your problem

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I edited that. @KareemEmad

Comment: You get that error because `f_name.split('_')` assumes that your filenames have four components separated by `_` but one of the filenames does not seem to meet that assumption; thus, [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) fails.

Comment: Do the files in that directory follow a certain convention for naming, i assume they all named ```text_text_text_text```, I mean are they all strictly following that format or there could be others written like ```name.txt``` with less than 3 underscores in name

Comment: Yes @KareemEmad that's right. Originally, the file names were like that. 

Which is why it worked perfectly when the first files were originally named text_text_text_text.  

But now when if I add another file with the previous text_text_text_text format, it won't continue the loop and I'll get that error.

Comment: Okay, the error you are facing means that there is a file that has no underscores at all in that directory,  you could know that file by adding a little check
```if f_name.count('_') < 3:  print('File name is malformed', f_name); continue```

Comment: That worked! Thank you :) @KareemEmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is occurring because it is encountering a file that does not fit the format you expect ... of four parts separated by `_`.

You could cope with this by using a `try ... except ...` around the line in question and `continue`-ing the loop if it does not fit that format.

```
for f in os.listdir('/home/rachellegarcia/Documents/agreements'):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    try:
        f_patient, f_conf, f_agmt, f_email = f_name.split('_')
    except ValueError:
        # ... it wasn't the format expected, skip it
        continue

    # ... it was the format expected
    f_agmt_type, f_agmt_staff = f_agmt.split('-')

    #sets the new name
    new_name = '{}-{}{}'.format(f_agmt_staff, f_email, f_ext)

    #renames the file
    os.rename(f, new_name.replace('-', '@'))
```

In the long run it may be more robust to check each filename against a regular expression that describes the exact format you expect.